# Amazon SES not sending to all e-mails, only approved

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses, laravel-vapor

I have a Laravel app going in Vapor and I'm trying to send e-mails via Amazon SES.

Everything works fine with the e-mails I have verified in SES, but not other e-mails.

My SES account is moved from Sandbox to Production.

```
Production Access   Enabled
Mail type   Transactional
Website URL <url>
Use case description    sending codes for verifying e-mail
Additional contact addresses    none
Preferred contact language  English
```

How can I get SES to send e-mails any address?

Comment: As in you can only send to verified address or you can only send from verified addresses?

Comment: I can only send to addresses that I have verified in the SES console.

Comment: Go to https://console.aws.amazon.com/ses/ and check the status of your SES account. Verify if it is still in sandbox or moved to production.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but please read my post. Production Access is Enabled.

Comment: What error(s)/responses are you getting when you try and send to a non-verified address?

Comment: I don't get any errors. Everything looks fine, but I never get an e-mail. And the sender count in SES don't count.

Comment: Did you figure out, I dtry to implement SES in Vapor also, but no email is sending. Does `production` need?

Comment: No. I changed from Vapor to Digital ocean. Not only due to this, but all in all Amazon is just too complicated for SMB.